# I want login with Azure AD in IOS

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory

i was try so many code and so many references but i didn't found any thing about Azure Ad login in ios (Swift). i want just login with Fb and login with Gmail . same thing i want in Azure Ad login in ios. please help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on#saml-sso) you probably will need your own server to redirect the user to Azure AD and then back to your server to log you in.

You need to share more details on what you're implementing and what you're using

Comment: i can't found any proper solution in this link . i already study this link

Comment: it's a standard SAML integration. It seems they don't have a guide for it, but anything will work. You just plug in the urls and keys you get from the Azure AD

Comment: first: https://support.knowbe4.com/hc/en-us/articles/229661667. You then need to integrate a SAML authentication system. What's your server backend?